# Javascript creating object in if not carrying over

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var cleanname = v.name.replace(/\s/g, "_").toLowerCase();
if(typeof(kpiValues[v.category]) === "undefined") {
  kpiValues[v.category] = {};
  if(typeof(kpiValues[v.category][cleanname] === "undefined")) {
    kpiValues[v.category][cleanname] = [];
  }
}
if(departments !== "default") {
  if(typeof(kpiValues[v.category][cleanname][0]) === "undefined") {
    kpiValues[v.category][cleanname][0] = {};
    kpiValues[v.category][cleanname][0].value = 0;
  }
}
```

This line:

```
if(typeof(kpiValues[v.category][cleanname][0]) === "undefined") {
```

throws me an error, and I am completely confused on why. In the first if-block, I ensure it builds out the object/array, but for some reason that I can't understand, it throws this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `typeof` is not function in Javascript so use like `typeof kpiValues[v.category][cleanname][0]`.

Comment: If `typeof(kpiValues[v.category]` is not undefined then first if-block is never entered and `kpiValues[v.category][cleanname]` might never get created.

Comment: Completely correct Johnny - this was a part of my issue. This helped me locate my actual problem:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not a function in Javascript so you can use like

```
typeof oprand
```

Consider this:

```
if(typeof kpiValues[v.category][cleanname][0]  === "undefined") {
```

Comment: This (partially) fixed my problem, and at least helped me find my actual problem: `typeof(kpiValues[v.category][cleanname] === "undefined"**)**)`